# Law of the Iterated Logarithm Bound (Finite Number of Crossings)

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_1,X_2,...)$ be i.i.d random variables with mean  $0$ and variance $1$. By the Law of the Iterated Logarithm, for all $\epsilon >0$,

\begin{equation}
P\left[ \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^{t}X_i \geq (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{\frac{2\log \log t}{t}}\text{ i.o.}\right] =0
\end{equation}

I want to show that 
\begin{equation}
P\left(\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^{t}X_i<(1+\epsilon)\sqrt{\frac{2\log \log t}{t}}\text{ for all }t \geq 3 , \;\epsilon >0\right) >0
\end{equation}
i.e. with positive probability, $\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}X_i$ never exceeds the LIL bound.

Comment: I believe the LIL itself is not strong enough to deduce what you want. You should search for the rate of convergence in the LIL.